# Zend Framework - In oop principle, how can the method '$this->getRequest()->getPost()' to work?

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework

How can the method below to work?

```
$this->getRequest()->getPost();
```

There is no method `getPost()` in class `Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract`, but how can it work? In OOP principle, the method `getPost()` should appear in `Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract`.

How can the Zend pull `getPost()` in class `Zend_Controller_Request_Http` if there is no direct instance?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zend will first send all your requests to FrontController which is available at Zend/Controller/Front.php. FrontController will inject the Http request into the controller here is the code where it is happening

```
    /**
     * Instantiate default request object (HTTP version) if none provided
     */
    if (null !== $request) {
        $this->setRequest($request);
    } elseif ((null === $request) && (null === ($request = $this->getRequest()))) {
        require_once 'Zend/Controller/Request/Http.php';
        $request = new Zend_Controller_Request_Http();
        $this->setRequest($request);
    }
```

> The purpose of frontcontroller is to **initialize the request
>   environment**, route the incoming request, and then dispatch any
>   discovered actions; it aggregates any responses and returns them when
>   the process is complete.

More about the FrontController [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.front.html)

To further answer your query

```
/**
 * Return the Request object
 *
 * @return Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract
 */
public function getRequest()
{
    return $this->_request;
}
```

this is what you will in Zend/Controller/Action.php - here comment says Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract '**is-a**' return type. I highlighted 'is-a' because it can return any class which 'is-a' Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract. To more about is-a check this [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) page

> "In knowledge representation, object-oriented programming and design,
>   is-a or is_a or is a (subsumption) is a relationship where one class D
>   is a subclass of another class B (and so B is a superclass of D)."

Comment: Thank you for answer. But then if Zend is applying `setRequest(new Zend_Controller_Request_Http())`, as you can see above, then the method `getRequest()` should return the type `Zend_Controller_Request_Http`, but is returning `Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract` type, which is making me confused. Thanks.

Comment: Please, see my review of @Tim Fountain, at the top.

Answer (score 2):

`getPost()` is part of the `Zend_Controller_Request_Http` Class which extends the `Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract`.

Comment: Okay, but follow my reasoning: when we apply `$this->getRequest()`, it returns the type `Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract`, right? So, through this type of class, there is no method `getPost()`.

Comment: This is how class inheritance works. getRequest() does not return an instance of `Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract`, it returns an instance of `Zend_Controller_Request_Http`, but this class extends `Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract`. Computer Science classes usually use simple examples like "Employee extends Person" to explain this sort of thing. So a getEmployee() method might return an instance of 'Employee', but an 'Employee' is still a Person.

Comment: Oh, you're right. When I applied now `var_dump($this->getRequest())` actually returns the instance of `Zend_Controller_Request_Http`. However, if you enter the class Zend/Controller/Action in the method `public function getRequest()`, the message states that returns `Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract`, which confused me. Thanks you.

Comment: of course, the getRequest Method dont know which instance of its returning. you could also extended the Framework to use FTP (bad example) instead of HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

Although I have voted to close the question ("this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion"), I think you raise an interesting point. I think that the ZF dev team can be defended as follows:

As far as the framework is concerned, an Action need only implement `Zend_Controller_Action_Interface`, which is essentially just the `dispatch()` method. The framework provide an abstract implementing class `Zend_Controller_Action` that we as userland app developers typically extend to define our action methods, etc. But there is nothing in that class that actually requires an instance of `Zend_Controller_Request_Http`. There is no inherent dependence upon `$request->getPost()` in framework code. It's only in userland that we app developers typically use the default dispatch flow that creates the `Zend_Controller_Request_Http` instance, which in turn gives us access to the POST via the `getPost()` method.

One could just as easily create MVC apps for CLI - where the notion of POST really doesn't apply - using a different subclass of `Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract` as its request mechanism.